# How to draw a closed path outward or inward, centering the line

Tags: tikz-pgf, line, shapes

When I have multiple shapes that are close to each other the picture is too busy to be considered "readable".

I would like to shift the media point of the line outward or inward as I need, but I haven't found anything about it in the tikz docs.

Example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
        \draw (0,0)     rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (0.5,0.5) circle    (0.5);        % this should draw inward
        \draw (0.5,0.5) circle    (0.5*1.414);  % this should draw outward
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see it would be a better picture with both circles drawn with a line centered out or in from the center.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe as *inward* and *outward* doesn't apply here, since the line width is always applied equally on both sides of the path. If you want one circle drawn inward and the other outward, you'll have to adjust the radii, depending on the line widths.

[image: inward/outward]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
        \draw (0,0)     rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (0.5,0.5) circle[radius=0.5cm-\pgflinewidth];        % this is drawn inward
        \draw (0.5,0.5) circle[radius=0.5*1.414cm+\pgflinewidth];  % this is drawn outward
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```